# Using wp_editor tinyMCE in metabox cause form alert on leaving page

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, wysiwyg

Using tinyMCE as wp_editor in a custom post type metabox create an alert when I try to submit or If I want to change location

[image]

I don't have such behavior using Quicktags, but since TinyMCE is easier to use I'd like to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be wordpress 5.6 issue,

I fixed it by disabling autosave()

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'disable_autosave' );
function disable_autosave() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'autosave' );
}
```

Or you can downgrade your version of wordpress.

You can also check the issue oncore.trac.wordpress.org
See this answer : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/383609/post-category-behave-like-a-post-in-back-office-menu

Comment: This bug has been on version 5.7